# Differences between Matlab FFT and Opencv DFT c++ code

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I'm trying to convert code from Matlab to OpenCV, 
I apply FFT\DFT on top of an image, multiply by amplitude (scale it) than bring the image back using dft.

I receive different results using matlab fft and Opencv DFT, which is exacly what am I trying to solve here.

What am I trying to solve here is the following: 
**I'd like to receive an identical results to the matlab, but still using an optimal DFT size in the opencv command.**

In matlab I pad the image for the FFT usage, 2*N + 1 .
In opencv I pad the image in the size given to me by  the function called:

```
  getOptimalDFTSize
```

What's really bother me is the fact that if I discard the getOptimalDFTSize  command in opencv, and use 2*N +1 I receive an identical result to the Matlab. 
But if I use the getOptimalDFTSize   command, the results are totally different.

I insist to use the getOptimalDFTSize   because it should make my code faster.

The matlab code:

building the filter

```
   [m,n] = size(img);
  %M = 2*m+1; N = n*2+1;
  M = 2*m; N = n*2;


  [X, Y] = meshgrid(1:N,1:M);
  CentX = ceil(N/2);
  CentY = ceil(M/2);
  dist = (X-CentX).*(X-CentX)+(Y-CentY).*(Y-CentY);
  H = (GammaH-GammaL)*(1-exp(-dist/(2*D0.^2)))+GammaL;

  % applying the filter
  IMG =fft2(Limg,M,N);
  H = fftshift(H);
  Iret = real(ifft2(IMG.*H));
  Iret = Iret(1:m,1:n);
  Iend = exp(Iret)-1;
```

My Opencv c++ code

```
//--------------------------UserInputStart
double m_GammaL = 0.02;
double m_GammaH = 1.2;
double m_D0 = 30;
//--------------------------UserInputEnd

int imageType = /*CV_64FC1 */CV_32F;
// Convert the input image into float 
Mat inputImage32f; 
inputImage8uchar->convertTo(inputImage32f,imageType);

// Convert the image from 0 to 1 scale , matlab corespondance : Limg = log(im2double(img)+1); 
inputImage32f = inputImage32f / 255;
inputImage32f = inputImage32f + 1; 

// Create a log image 
Mat logImage;
cv::log(inputImage32f,logImage);

// Apply the filter 

// Transform the image into the special domain
Mat paddedLogImage;                            //expand input image to optimal size
int m = getOptimalDFTSize( logImage.rows );
int n = getOptimalDFTSize( logImage.cols ); // on the border add zero pixels
copyMakeBorder(logImage, paddedLogImage, 0, m - logImage.rows, 0, n - logImage.cols,
    BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0));

Mat homoFilter(paddedLogImage.rows,paddedLogImage.cols,imageType);
Mat*  p_homoFilter = &homoFilter;
// Handle the homomorphic filter 
CreateHomomorphFilter(p_homoFilter,paddedLogImage.cols,paddedLogImage.rows,m_GammaL, m_GammaH , m_D0);

// Shift the filter 
(*p_homoFilter) = (*p_homoFilter)(Rect(0, 0, (*p_homoFilter).cols & -2, (*p_homoFilter).rows & -2));
int cx = (*p_homoFilter).cols/2;
int cy = (*p_homoFilter).rows/2;

Mat q0((*p_homoFilter), Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));   // Top-Left - Create a ROI per quadrant
Mat q1((*p_homoFilter), Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));  // Top-Right
Mat q2((*p_homoFilter), Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));  // Bottom-Left
Mat q3((*p_homoFilter), Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy)); // Bottom-Right

// swap quadrants (Top-Left with Bottom-Right)
Mat tmp;                   
q0.copyTo(tmp);
q3.copyTo(q0);
tmp.copyTo(q3);

// swap quadrant (Top-Right with Bottom-Left)
q1.copyTo(tmp);                    
q2.copyTo(q1);
tmp.copyTo(q2);

Mat complexI;
Mat planes[] = {Mat_<float>(paddedLogImage), Mat::zeros(paddedLogImage.size(), imageType)};
merge(planes, 2, complexI);         // Add to the expanded another plane with zeros

// this way the result may fit in the source matrix
dft(paddedLogImage, complexI,/*cv::DFT_SCALE|*/cv::DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT);
split(complexI, planes);

//planes[0] = planes[0].mul((*p_homoFilter));

multiply(planes[0],(*p_homoFilter),planes[0],1,imageType);
multiply(planes[1],(*p_homoFilter),planes[1],1,imageType);

merge(planes, 2, complexI);

// Back to image scope 
idft(complexI, complexI,cv::DFT_SCALE|cv::DFT_INVERSE/*|cv::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT*/);
split(complexI, planes);

// Use only the planes[0] which is the real number 
complexI = planes[0];

// Crop the relevant image values 
Mat outputImage32f(complexI, Rect(0, 0, inputImage8uchar->cols,inputImage8uchar->rows));
```

What am I trying to solve here is the following: I'd like to receive an identical results to the matlab, but still using an optimal DFT size in the opencv command.

---

Regarding to the opencv command , Get optimal DFT size

getOptimalDFTSize
Returns the optimal DFT size for a given vector size.

DFT performance is not a monotonic function of a vector size. Therefore, when you calculate convolution of two arrays or perform the spectral analysis of an array, it usually makes sense to pad the input data with zeros to get a bit larger array that can be transformed much faster than the original one. Arrays whose size is a power-of-two (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...) are the fastest to process. Though, the arrays whose size is a product of 2’s, 3’s, and 5’s (for example, 300 = 5*5*3*2*2) are also processed quite efficiently.

The function getOptimalDFTSize returns the minimum number N that is greater than or equal to vecsize so that the DFT of a vector of size N can be processed efficiently. In the current implementation N = 2 p * 3 q * 5 r for some integer p, q, r.

### Solved

It took me a while to solve this problem , eventually there was no differences in the code, however there was a difference in the sampling rate between Matlab and OpenCV.

If I'd change the sampling rate in OpenCV things would have worked out but I'd have to pay in higher running time

I guess Opencv supported  DFT vs Matlab with FFT standard

Comment: There isn't a question here. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This isn't clear; you are using a different FFT size and are wondering why you get a different result?

Comment: Actually , I'd assume to receive the same results, the only reason using DFT is because opencv doesn't support FFT,  however in FFT a padding is necessary in order to receive power of 2 scale

Comment: What value does 'getOptimalDFTSize' give you? And how do you use this value? It's not really clear from your code..

Comment: getOptimalDFTSize gives me the following multiplication 2,4 for the given input, I use this value for the DFT size, 
I changed my code in order to support it 

I rephrase my question , please take it off from "on hold"

Comment: You will *not* get the correct result if you do not pad appropriately.

Comment: Ok, I guess my problem is understanding the properties of FFT

Comment: OpenCV’s `dft` function computes the FFT, just like MATLAB’s `fft2` does. MATLAB’s uses FFTW, which is significantly faster than OpenCV’s for sizes that are not multiples of small integers. Padding to `2*N+1` is the weirdest thing I’ve seen. You’re better off not padding at all (time it and you’ll see).